# What Asian Nations would have the capacity to colonize the New World?

Tags: internal-consistency, alternate-history, colonization, colonies

In an alternate history I am designing, the Mayans and the Aztec start a lot earlier and become much more powerful, domesticated more animals and thus contracting plagues, These plagues spread across the Americas and destroys the population. By the time Columbus arrives, he also brings back diseases while giving them to the Natives.

In this timeline, the colonization of North America does not start until the late sixteenth century and when it does occur, it takes a lot longer. By the time the Europeans successfully colonize Oklahoma, I want Asia to begin travelling across the North Pacific and colonizing the West Coast.

What Asian nations of the sixteenth century would have had the most capacity (resources, technology, skills, personnel) to colonize the West Coast?

Comment: Russia did semi-colonize the pacific coastline of North America at one point (1650ish).  Or did you want earlier?

Comment: @Twelfth for one, when I say 16th century I mean 1500-1600, secondly that wasn't a truly successful colonization.

Comment: true...small settlements, not colonization.   You might need some alterations to history here.  16th century is fall of the ming dynasty and that would make colonization difficult.  Mongols have already gone, Japan was completely isolationist until they invaded korea at the end of the 16th century.  Much of southeast asia was just starting to experience imperialism themselves...there isn't an obvious candidate until Russia a century later

Comment: @Twelfth thats the point of the question, there isn't any obvious nation from a glance

Comment: The Mughal empire in India was still in it's infancy (even being overthrown but eventually regaining power) in the 16th century.  There isn't the same scarcity of land and persecution within Asia that led to the European mass colonization of the Americas.  Best answer I can give is pretty heavily altered history.

Comment: @Twelfth hence the tag, alternate history

Comment: There was a time when the Chinese were truly successful seafarers. Sadly a little too early ~1400. But since you take some liberties, you might consider it as well. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zheng_He

Comment: +1 To the Chinese, their treasure fleets during the 15th century made great leaps in exploration. You do not say when in the 16th century colonisation starts butbitbcoukd be before the fall of the Ming dynasty.If you are intrested this BBC radio documentary is worth listening to.http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b015p8c2

Comment: Yeah but if you go with china, you should mention that the book "1421: The Year China Discovered the World" is actually fact (though the contents wouldn't be the same). You should check other [pre-colunbian contact theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-Columbian_trans-oceanic_contact_theories).

Comment: Just a note that there aren't any more animals to domesticate in Americas.

Comment: @Euphoric and? What does that have to do with the question?

Comment: From the discussion in the comments, it seems history would have to undergo a rather drastic alteration to make this viable. The best answer, then, is simply the one you like best. There's no objective criteria to determine the "best" answer,

Comment: Heh, took the time to prepare an answer only for the question to go on hold.  With some altered history, China is your best choice...however they were somewhat on the receiving end of imperialism via the portuguese and later dutch + spanish.  Part of the Ming dynasty's collapse can be traced to what European influence did the the price of silver.  The Chinese had the technology and means to colonize, but the driving factors behind European colonization just aren't there in the same manner.

Comment: China is too far from the Americas. Period. It was difficult enough sailing in the 1700s, but without an accurate way to keep time at sea, you wouldn't know how far you've gone or your longitude. One could stop at ports along the way, but the Chinese would have to develop Hawaii and not lose too many ships on the long distances or get stuck in doldrums.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more fact based, hoping it will get opened, but do not know how to initiate a request to reopen this (@Aify)  The reason is that I have what I consider a better answer.  When Hideyoshi invaded China, they had the resources, technology and skills to colonize the Americas.  I would have Japan engender an explorer who gets Hideyoshi's backing to go exploring for new lands and comes back in the nick of time to keep Hideyoshi from wasting the resources on an invasion and instead use them to colonize a land with very few peoples who would be no match for Japan.

Comment: I agree with China as per the book 1421 mentioned by necessity. The book is Gavin Menzies and is super convincing, although it seems most historians discredit it.

Comment: @AgapwIesu Editing it should put it in the review queues automatically. When you have 3000 rep you can click a button on a question to nominate for reopening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if you're going for the late 16th century why not have Japan, Korea and China colonize it after Hideyoshi tried to invade China and Korea?

The invasions might have been successfully repelled by the Koreans and Chinese, but it did drain the Chinese treasury and destroyed a good part of the Korean countryside cities. They would most likely be looking to rebuild and restock, what better place to do that than in a whole new land? As for capabilities, the Chinese had quite an impressive Imperial Fleet. from what I read.

Japan on the other hand might be looking to colonize the West Coast either for resources, expansion or simply to thwart the Chinese/Korean efforts. They should have a decent part of the armada left that Nobunaga used for his naval blockade of the Mori clan.

Also, it might be more fun if the Chinese and Koreans joined up to defend themselves against the Japanese. It adds a lot of possibility for a sketchy alliance, where one side is afraid the other will betray them eventually.

This way, you could also have them fight over it if you want, or start a little cold war.